# How do you translate "to be impressed by sth./so." in German?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> ***Ich imponierte sie mit meinem Kochen***
>
> I impressed her with my cooking.

I wonder if I can replace ***mit*** with ***durch*** in this context?

> ***Ich beeindruckte ihre Eltern durch meine Höflichkeit.***
>
> I impressed her parents by my politeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jemanden beeindrucken mit etwas` und `jemandem imponieren mit etwas` scheinen mir austauschbar.

Wobei `beindrucken` mit dem Akkusativ benutzt wird ...

> Ich beeindruckte *wen*? Ich beeindruckte *ihre* Eltern durch meine Höflichkeit.
>
> Ich beeindrucke *wen*? Ich beindrucke *sie* mit meinem Kochen.

... `imponieren` dagegen mit dem Dativ.

> Ich imponiere *wem*? Ich imponiere *ihr* mit meinem Kochen.
>
> Ich imponierte *wem*? Ich imponierte *ihren* Eltern durch meine Höflichkeit.

---

**Update:**
However, the more literal translation of this passive use of `to impress` (`to be impressed by sth./so.`) would be `beeindruckt sein von etwas/jemandem`.

Comment: Wobei `imponieren` teilweise schon etwas fast Übertriebenes meinen kann. `Imponiergehabe` tönt nach Macho.

Comment: @PMF: Hmm ... mag sein, liegt aber doch wohl eher an `Gehabe`, als an `imponieren`.

Comment: Wohl wahr, aber das Wort kommt halt häufig in dem Zusammenhang vor.

Comment: @PMF: Kommt sicher auch auf das Umfeld und den Sprachraum an. Ich empfinde an Aussagen, wie "Ihre Fahrkünste imponierten." or "Er imponierte durch seine Hartnäckigkeit." nix Übertriebenes; wenn die denn wirklich so gut waren ... latürnich?-)